# How do I make the gradient background change each time page has reload while also keeping the cursor position element active?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is the code I'm currently using... cursor position not working in the codepen but working in my browser

http://cdpn.io/QNxPor

Comment: The link doesn't work and give me this error `The owner of this Pen needs to verify their email address to enable Full Page View.` Also why you didn't  put your code here to evaluate and check. If the link fails (like is happening right now) the developer cannot review your code.

Comment: The code was too long and it was my first pen. it is there now

Answer (score 0):

Need add external JavaScript [//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js)
And move js code inside html (`<body></body>`) to javascript block.
See [here](http://codepen.io/asm-jaime/pen/reKbgb).